Getting active conference Google Meet API
I am using @google-apps/meet in my node.js app in order to get real ending time of a meeting.
I tried different methods from Meet API and always get same behaviour.
Maybe I should use Reports API to get real ending time of google meeting? If so, please help me to use this api with Admin SDK, because I don't have Google Admin Console
Here is my code. In response I'm getting this (sencetive data changed) if I am a creator of meeting (I see my user and other active attendees):
{ 
name: 'conferenceRecords/c00fb000-0000-40c9-9b0b-4b1bf1cd5c00/participants/000000000000000000000', 
earliestStartTime: { seconds: '1722932647', nanos: 766303000 }, 
latestEndTime: { seconds: '1722932745', nanos: 88111000 }, 
signedinUser: { 
user: 'users/000000000000000000000', 
displayName: 'User Name' }, 
user: 'signedinUser' } 

If I am not a creator, just a participant I don't get any data about this meeting. How can I get similar response for those meetings, where I am just a participant?
Here is my code
const { SpacesServiceClient, ConferenceRecordsServiceClient } = require("@google-apps/meet").v2; 
const { sendNotification } = require("../services/notification.service"); 

const processEvents = async (authClient) => { 
   // GET Meet API space name by conferenceId from Calendar API 
   const spacesClient = new SpacesServiceClient({ authClient }); 
   const meetingClient = new ConferenceRecordsServiceClient({ authClient }); 
   for (const event of events) { 
      if (event.conferenceData?.conferenceId) { 
         const conferenceId = event.conferenceData.conferenceId; 
         // console.log(conferenceId); 
         const spacesRequest = { name: spaces/${conferenceId} }; 
      try { 
         const sessions = meetingClient.listConferenceRecordsAsync({ 
            parent: conferenceId, }); 
         for await (let session of sessions) { 
         // console.log("SESSIONS ==> ", session); 
         //set plan end time for meeting in db 
         //if session.endTime is null, set meetingEnded to false 
         //if session.endTime is not null, set meetingEnded to true, send notification 
         const partisipants = await meetingClient.listParticipants({ 
            parent: session.name }); 
         for await (let partisipant of partisipants) { 
             console.log("PARTISIPANT ==> ", partisipant); } }; 
             const spaces = await spacesClient.getSpace(spacesRequest); // 
             console.log("SPACE ==> ", spaces); 
             console.log( "spaces[0]?.activeConference =====", spaces[0]?.activeConference ); } } 
      catch (error) { 
         console.error( Error processing event for conferenceId ${conferenceId}:, error ); } } } };

module.exports = { processEvents, };

